# How do I set up Aqemu / kvm tap device?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to use Aqemu and I'm trying to figure out how to just have the network in the virtual machine connected to a tap device on the real machine. How do I set this up? Do I need to make the tap device before hand? What should I set in Aqemu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the network tab.

Pick "Basic" for "Network Settings GUI type".

For the network card "Connection Mode", pick "Open a TUN/TAP interface".

Make sure "TUN/TAP Script" is unchecked.

Put in an interface name.

After you start the VM, you need to set the TAP interface as started.

```
 sudo ifconfig tap1 up
```

You will probably also want to add IP addresses to the interface:

```
ip addr add 192.168.13.1/24 dev tap1
#ipv6 example
ip -6 addr add 2001:D8B8:E89D:389C::1/64 dev tap1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see my question here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/73765/qemu-networking-problems-when-trying-to-get-it-to-connect-with-the-host-bridgin

which may include some answers to your question.